# .htcaccess file assistance needed for canonicalization

Tags: seo

My website currently has two version to google, https://www.example.com and a https://example.com This is apparently not good for SEO as its leaking all my seo 'juice' away. I have already told google to use just the www version around 5 weeks ago but come results on google still show the non-www version. I was wondering if anyone could help with my .htaccess to get the redirect right to just www.

The htcaccess file is copied below:

```
RewriteEngine on
# Force SSL
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond $1 !^(blog)

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^`.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.`.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !public/
RewriteRule (.*) /public/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a simple redirect you can use:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

If you want to also force HTTPS:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

**Note:** This block goes above the `www.` rewrite rules to make sure both rules take hold

Comment: Worked like a charm. Oh I wish I could buy you a beer!

Comment: Glad it worked! Make sure to upvote and mark the answer as accepted so other people can also benefit from the answer!